# Classic ASP Remove Excel Line Breaks

Tags: csv, asp-classic

Trying to replace the line breaks that excel puts between sentences in a cell when converted to a tab delimited csv.
Have tried various different methods `chr(10)`, `chr(13)`, `vbcrlf`, `vblf`, `\n` etc.

This is a big problem as it is causing my array to break.

**Code :**

```
response.write replace(replace(sLine,vbtab,""),CHR(),"|||")
```

Basically tried the replace with loads of different methods.

Comment: `response.write replace(replace(sLine,vbtab,""),CHR(),"|||")`

Basically tried the replace with loads of different methods

Comment: Does your code really try to call CHR with no argument?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all line breaks before, after, and in between. Select your cell or range of cells then run the marco. If you are looking to replace the before and after but leave only one line break between lines but no blank lines. I have one that can do that.

```
Sub RemoveLineBreaks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strOldVal As String
    Dim strNewVal As String

    For Each rngCell In Selection
        If rngCell.HasFormula = False Then
            strOldVal = rngCell.Value
            strNewVal = strOldVal
            Debug.Print rngCel.Address

            Do

            strNewVal = Replace(strNewVal, vbLf, " ")

            If strNewVal = strOldVal Then Exit Do
                strOldVal = strNewVal
            Loop

            If rngCell.Value <> strNewVal Then
                rngCell = strNewVal
            End If
        End If
        rngCell.Value = Application.Trim(rngCell.Value)
    Next rngCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```